# OO Class Design - interacting two classes for searching

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I'm trying to design my classes for a personal project but I'm stuck. I have much more experience in database design and can't find the OO solution to how my classes should best relate/interact.

My (PHP) project is a tool that will search for a given `phrase` throughout one or many `pages` of a single website. The output should show the phrase, how many times it was found, which pages it was found on, and how many times it occurred on that page.

So a phrase can have many related pages, and a page can contain many phrases.

I'm having a hard time grasping how to relate my two classes. I know that my `phrase` class will need to store the text phrase and the `page` class will need information about itself (page URL, page name, page content, etc).

Beyond that, I don't see where to logically store my methods that will need to

- Search a page (or many pages) for a phrase
- count how many times a phrase was found across all pages that were searched
- count how many times a phrase occurred on each specific page
- provide an excerpt of (for example) 20 characters surrounding each occurrence of the phrase from the page
- return an array for the specific phrase containing the above information

Would it make sense to have a `phraseFinder` class that will take a `phrase` and one or more `page`(s), and have all these methods and information stored there?

Comment: Yep, the search algorithm should be isolated into its own class. I would implement it in a map reduce fashion.

Comment: Where is the page content? Will you search html pages or, you want to load the content of page into Page object, and then search the phrase there. These two cases will require different solution?

Comment: All of the page content is stored in a database. It's not required to load them into their own objects but I figured it would be best for my design in case I want to search other sources in the future.

Answer (score 0):

> Search a page (or many pages) for a phrase

SearchService

> count how many times a phrase was found across all pages that were searched...

I suggest you first model a nested structure, describing the result your search service needs to return to the application as a simple JSON object. Then turn each object or array there into a class in your code like this:

```
{
  "occurrenceInfo": {
    "phrase": "cat",
    "page": {
      "id": 30,
      "name": "Cat runs on the legs"
    },
    "occurrenceCount": 50,
    "occurrences": [
      {
        "position": 500,
        "excerpt": "a portion of text of the cat"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can turn it into OccurenceInfo, PhraseInfo, PageInfo, PageOccurenceInfo etc classes.